# laravel: routing error when sending validation error messages

Tags: php, laravel

I do not understand what is wrong with this code being at the address `127.0.0.1:8000/getIncomingTransfers` I am trying to process a form by sending it to the address `127.0.0.1:8000/authenticateTransfer` but I get the error **The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**

in my web.php file

```
Route::name('reference')->post('getIncomingTransfers', [MainController::class, 'getIncomingTransfers']);
Route::name('security')->post('authenticateTransfer', [MainController::class, 'authenticateTransfer']);
```

in my `getIncomingTransfers.blade.php` file

```
    <form action="{{ route('security') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('SecurityAnswer') ? 'error' : '' }}" name="SecurityAnswer" id="SecurityAnswer">
            <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary solid">Confirm</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Error -->
        @if ($errors->has('SecurityAnswer'))
            <div class="error" style="text-align: center; color: brown">
                 {{ $errors->first('SecurityAnswer') }}
            </div>
        @endif
 </form>
```

in my `MainController@authenticateTransfer` file

```
public function authenticateTransfer(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
      'SecurityAnswer' => 'required',
   ]);
   return $request;
}
```

when I click on the submit button of the form with the `SecurityAnswer` field not empty there is no error but when the validation fails and the message of the validation error must be returned that's where I have this error. how can i solve the problem?.
I also want to specify that the `getIncomingTransfers` route is in `POST` by which a form is received to be processed before returning the view `getIncomingTransfers.blade.php`

Comment: failed validation will throw an exception that will cause a redirect BACK ... your form should be provided by a GET route not a POST route (since the redirect is a GET request)

Comment: if you need to call your form via POST instead of GET, you have also the chance to give both methods to your route, to bypass the 'method not supported' error. So using `Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function ()...` it should works fine. In addition you should declare as required your input field in html form yo avoid empty submissions

Comment: @lagbox is correct.  At the end of a previous POST call, you probably load this view.  You should always return a redirect from a POST route never a view.  The problem is what you did BEFORE showing this form, not with the code you show.

Comment: thank you very much @Snapey  the redirection solved the problem